# Checking for Season According to DataFrame Month Number in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the current DataFrame:

[image]

I am trying to loop through each of the rows checking the month number and then according to the month number, assign the season for that month in a separate column. I haven't had much success when trying to loop through the rows and assigning values that way. Any ideas what I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a dictionary assigning months to seasons.
For an example,

```py
seasons = {1: 'Winter', 2:'Summer', 3: 'Spring'}
# This assigns January to Winter, February to Summer and March to Spring. Just an example.
```

Then apply a lambda function using [pandas apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to create a new column.

```py
df['Season'] = df['Month No.'].apply(lambda x: seasons[x])
```

Comment: This makes sense. What does the lambda function do that is different to a normal function if you wouldn't mind me asking?

Comment: apply() function takes in a function. I've used a lambda function to make this easier(so all of it can be written in single line). You can use a normal function instead of a lambda. You need to define the function and pass its name into apply(). More examples and explanations can be found at apply [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).